# Как сохранить значения checkbox в localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть чекбоксы 1, 2, 3, 4, их значение сохряняется в localstorage. Еще есть "кнопка" "Убрать галочки". При нажатии на нее галочки с чекбоксов снимаются.

https://jsfiddle.net/qomugek2/1/

```
/* Сохранить switch checkbox */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    var checkboxId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      localStorage.setItem(checkboxId, 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(checkboxId);
    }
  });
  for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    if (value == 1) {
      $('#' + key).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
  }
});

// Убрать все switch checkbox
function uncheck() {
 var uncheck=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i=0;i<uncheck.length;i++) {
  if(uncheck[i].type=='checkbox') {
   uncheck[i].checked=false;
  }
 }
}
```

Проблема в том, что нужно чтобы после этого значения чекбоксов 1, 2, 3, 4 сохранились в localstorage. Но они не сохраняются. Что делать, ребята? Что делать?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function uncheck() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    this.checked = false;
    $(this).change();
  });
}
```

Comment: А у него после нажатия кнопки не сохраняются данные...))) То есть не удаляются данные каждого чекбокса, то есть полностью не чистится Storage))) Тогда может проще `localStorage.clear()` и готово))

Comment: @Leonid Опасаюсь выжигать весь `localStorage` :)

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, работает 

Comment: @Leonid Нет, нет, весь нельзя )) там еще много всякого разного

Comment: @Юра Пожалуйста. Успехов.